# How to handle Endpoint warnings in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, tomcat7, cxf, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.8.1,
I wish to handle warning of endpoints.I am trying to hit CXF services in tomcat server.
If I test with wrong action (Operation/method)name or service name in tomcat.
I am getting this message in SOAP.

```
<html>
   <body>No service was found.</body>
</html>
```

Where as in my wso2esb not getting logged any error and that particular endpoint failing showing this message.

```
[2014-11-24 16:57:57,931]  WARN - LoadbalanceEndpoint Endpoint [ServiceLEP] Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : Endpoint [EP3]
```

Since I don't know the CXF I wish to handle this in wso2esb How would I handle this message and send proper error response to client.
Is any one able to help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a  mediator, the response will be available in the inSequence.  You can log that response with code such as this after your  mediator:

```
<enrich> 
    <source type="body"/> 
    <target type="property" action="child" property="response_body"/> 
</enrich> 
<log level="custom"> 
    <property name="The Response" expression="get-property('response_body')"/> 
</log>
```

Please advise if that works in your scenario.

Comment: what is the use of above code after send mediator I kept this code I am getting request part not getting any error,So same I kept in OutSequence but its not printing,Flow is dicarding after send.

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is suspended, then WSO2 by default initiate fault sequence, you can define your custom message in the fault sequence and then send it back to the client as you want. You can get ERROR_CODE and ERROR_MESSAGE property  from WSO2 in Log or Switch mediator where u can check it. In log u can do it as following:

```
 <log level="full" separator="**********Fault Sequence File Processor***********">
      <property name="ErrorCode" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"></property>
      <property name="ErrorMessage" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"></property>
      <property name="ErrorDetail" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"></property>
      <property name="ErrrorException" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"></property>
   </log>
```

You can make a check on ERROR_CODE property or ERROR_MESSAGE property in **Switch** mediator and then with the help of **Payload** mediator u can define your custom error message.